# Unable to run python3 debugger in VSCode

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

## Issue

Currently I'm unable to debug python3 scripts in VSCode. Normally, after clicking "Start debugging" with the python3 interpreter set the VSCode terminal pops up and initiates the script. Now, nothing pops up, but when I look at the "Output" section I do see output assuming from the python extension after I click "Start debugging".

If I switch the interpreter to python 2.7 it works, but 3.7 does not. I reinstalled the python vscode extension and confirmed that the path to the python3 bin file is correct.

## Output

```
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3 ~/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2019.10.41019/pythonFiles/ptvsd_folder_name.py
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3 ~/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2019.10.41019/pythonFiles/ptvsd_folder_name.py
> /usr/bin/env python3 -c "import sys;print(sys.executable)"
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3 -c "import sys;print(sys.executable)"
```

## Specifications

#### VSCode Python Extension

Name: Python
Id: ms-python.python
Description: Linting, Debugging (multi-threaded, remote), Intellisense, Jupyter Notebooks, code formatting, refactoring, unit tests, snippets, and more.
Version: 2019.10.41019
Publisher: Microsoft
VS Marketplace Link: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python

#### VSCode

Version 1.36.1 (1.36.1)

#### OS

macOS 10.14.6 (18G4032)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't determine the cause. So I ended up deleting VSCode as well as removing all traces of python3. Finally, I reinstalled both as well as pylint and the python VSCode extension. This resolved the debugger issue.